# unexected EOF while parsing?

Tags: python-3.x

I would create a text adventure game. I'm going to add the rest in later. I got this error while testing this bit out to see if I remember stuff correctly. Guess I don't.

```
print("Welcome. This is a text adventure game. It is the first time I create 
\n something like this, so please be kind. Enjoy! \n Type \"start\" to start 
the game.\n Type \"quit\" to exit."
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a closing `)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your print seems to missing a closing bracket.